# Блок выходит за границы родительского

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

С данной проблемой я столкнулся, когда пытался расположить модальное окно по центру экрана, но и еще в некоторых местах. Ответ на тот свой вопрос я не получил, попробую описать заново.
У нас есть родительский блок и внутри еще один блок, который нам нужно расположить по центру. Сделаем это с помощью `display: flex`:

```css
html, body
{
  margin: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

footer
{
  margin-top: auto;
}

.page
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.parent
{
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child
{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Как видим, все отлично, прощу заметить, что у родительского блока есть минимальная высота 100vh. И теперь вот что мы получаем, если контента в дочернем блоке будет больше чем минимальная высота:

```css
html, body
{
  margin: 0;

    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

footer
{
  margin-top: auto;
}

.page
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


.parent
{
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child
{
  background-color: green;
  height: 110vh;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Как я заметил, данная проблема появляется только тогда, когда у этого `.parent` установлено `min-height` в процентах (`%`) или `vh`.

Comment: Так а проблема в чём?

Comment: Блок выходит за границы родительского.. Почему он его не расширяет?

Answer (score 2):

Один из вариантов, вместо `<body class="page">` - сделать обёртку с классом `.page`

```
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">

      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Либо поменяйте в css, в теге body `height: 100%` на `min-height: 100%`

**UPD**

Для того чтобы футер был в поле видимости, и находился внизу, у вас есть 2 варианта.

Первый - сделать футеру фиксированное позиционирование

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Тогда футер всегда будет в одном месте, даже при скролле.

Другой вариант, более логический, использовать `calc` в `css`.
Тогда футер будет внизу, если условный `.content` не занимает много места
Но подходит если знаете высоту футера.

```
.page {
  min-heigh: calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

Здесь 200px это высота футера.

---

Пример:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
footer {
  background: black;
  color: orange;
  height: 30px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px); /*100% - 30px в.хедера и 30px в.футера */
}

.child {
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

**ONE MORE UPD:**

Вариант на флексах

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
footer {
  background: black;
  color: orange;
  height: 50px;
}

.page {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: coral;
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
  flex-grow: 1; /* не пропустите это */
}

.child {
  background: pink;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Тогда для page придется опять же давать 100% высоту иначе футер не будет прижат. И проблема повторится.

Comment: @OliverPatterson а куда вы хотите прижать футер?

Comment: Очевидно, что к низу страницы. `margin-top: auto` позволяет это сделать, если родитель будет `display: flex`, но так же нужно чтобы родитель занимал всю высоту экрана, а для этого нужна высота 100%.

Comment: Поменяйте ```height``` на ```min-height```

Comment: Чудеса.. Чудеса! Я столько времени на это убил в свое время.. Отредактируйте ответ)

Comment: А хотя отмена.. Тогда футер не прижимается к низу..

Comment: @OliverPatterson обновил ещё раз

Comment: Увы, эти варианты не подходят.

Comment: Тогда не совсем понимаю что именно вам нужно. Я описал все варианты, при которых футер находится внизу

Comment: Для меня очень не логично, что при моем варианте, родительский блок не хочет расширяться, хотя у него стоит минимальная высота, а не фиксированная.

Comment: Посмотрите на пример который только что добавил. Так же я в функции  ```calc```  заменил ```100%``` на  ```100vh```  возможно ошибка была в этом

Comment: Ну а если высота не известна и она динамическая? Опять же, помимо того блока что между хеадером и футером будут еще и другие.

Comment: @OliverPatterson тогда попробуйте вариант на флексах, только что добавил