# Как прижать футер на мобильной версии Chrome

Tags: html, css

Я делаю чат, и хочу чтобы окно ввода текста было прижато к нижней части экрана. Я сделал абсолютное позиционирование и bottom: 0. На десктопе все работает отлично, но на мобильной версии хрома, когда шапка браузера уходит с экрана, снизу появляется пустота, будто bottom: 0 не учитывает изменение высоты с исчезанием шапки

Comment: А если position: sticky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
position: fixed
```

Решил мою проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Вчера давал ответ на похожий вопрос

Посмотрите часть "**ONE MORE UPD:**  Вариант на флексах"

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430568/Блок-выходит-за-границы-родительского/1430588#1430588](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430568/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/1430588#1430588)

Comment: Попробовал, теперь без шапки ввод текста под экраном

Comment: Надо как-то заставить его не менять свою позицию вне зависимости есть шапка браузера или нет